# how to retrieve MD5 password

Tags: php

I've put username and md5(password) on my MySQL database. Below is my old login PHP code. I want to add some code that can retrieve my md5 password, because on my old code there is no md5 password. Where is should I add md5(password)?

Here is my full login code:

```
<?
if ($_POST['username']) {
$username=trim($_POST['username']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password=trim($_POST['password']);
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($password);
//$password = hash('md5','$password');



if ($password==NULL) {
header("Location: login.php?error=2");
}else{

if($_POST['code']!=$_SESSION['string']){ 
header("Location: login.php?error=1");
}else{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM tb_users WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0)
{
header("Location: login.php?error=3");

} else {
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($data['password'] != $password) {
header("Location: login.php?error=4");
}else{

$query = mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM tb_users WHERE username='$username'  ") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

$nicke=$row['username'];
$passe=$row['password'];

setcookie("usNick",$nicke,time()+36000);
setcookie("usPass",$passe,time()+36000);

$lastlogdate=time();
$lastip = getRealIP();

$querybt = "UPDATE tb_users SET lastlogdate='$lastlogdate', lastiplog='$lastip' WHERE username='$nicke'";
mysql_query($querybt) or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT akhirupgrade from tb_upgrade WHERE username = '$username' and status='upgraded'") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$akhir=$row["akhirupgrade"];
$tgl=time();
if ($tgl > $akhir) {
$query = mysql_query("update tb_upgrade set status='', date='', paket='', akhirupgrade='' WHERE username='$username' and status='upgraded'");
$query = mysql_query("update tb_users set account='' WHERE username='$username'");
}
}
header("Location: member.php");
}

}

}

}

}

?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: I don't think `retrieve my md5 password` is what you want. You are really asking how to compare the plain text password against the hashed DB version to authenticate, right? As already noted you shouldn't use md5 anymore.

Comment: Use Sha256 when dealing with passwords. MD5 is unsecure and outdated.

Comment: can you give me a tutorial applying this sha256 to my code above, since i newbie here.

Comment: you can easily find that on google ;) Good luck

Comment: and what kind keyword for googling about this? thanks

Comment: @TyQ., no don't use SHA256. Use something specifically designed for passwords, like `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`. You shouldn't be dealing with hash details yourself.

Comment: Most of the times you can just search the MD5 hash in Google and it'll find the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use password_hash() if you running on php 5.5 or greater

When you send the password to the database simply hash it with the function

```
$password = password_hash(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"));
```

The when you pull the password back out of the database do the same thing to the password they submitted.

```
$passwordFromDb = $result['password']; //Password from the database
$passwordFromLoginForm = password_hash(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");

//Then when youve got the password to check it agaisnt there input

if($passwordFromDb === $passwordFromForm){
    //The password they entered was the same as the password in the database
} else {
    //The password was wrong
}
```

I have not tested this code so there may be errors but hopefully youll get the point :)

PS dont use MD5 please, Very insecure

If you must use md5

```
$password = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"));//Store password


$passwordFromDb = $result['password']; //Password from the database
$passwordFromLoginForm = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password");

//Then when youve got the password to check it agaisnt there input

if($passwordFromDb === $passwordFromForm){
    //The password they entered was the same as the password in the database
} else {
    //The password was wrong
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for replying my thread, i've tried your given method, but there is a problem,that the password result is empty on database mysql. since my code is old one, if i still want use MD5 or sha1 , what is the right code?

Comment: Have you checked in the database to see if the password went in ? 

To use MD5 

    $passwordFromForm = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"));

To put the password in the database then when you pull the hash back from the database you can compare with 

$passwordFromForm = md5(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "password"));
$passwordFromDb = $result['password'];

    if($passwordFromForm === $passwordFromDb) {
        //Password was correct
    } else {
        //Password was wrong 
    }

Please bear in mind you cannot just copy and paste this and hope it works

Ryan